# libpd on java UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, libpd

I am doing my first attempts to use `libpd` with java. The IDE I am using is NetBeans. For libpd I am using [these binary builds for Java](https://github.com/wivlaro/libpd-java-build).
When running the code I get a java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError. At some poit it says:

> Can't find dependent libraries

I've seen a similar question answered for Android, but not for Java.

EDIT: this is the full error-message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   C:\Users\jaiserpe\AppData\Local\Temp\pdnative7141399841793639340.dll:
>   Can't find dependent libraries    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1938)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1821)  at
>   java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)     at
>   java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)   at
>   org.puredata.core.NativeLoader.loadLibraryFromJar(NativeLoader.java:121)
>     at org.puredata.core.NativeLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLoader.java:97)
>     at org.puredata.core.PdBase.(PdBase.java:59)    at
>   holamundo.HolaMundo.main(HolaMundo.java:26)
>   C:\Users\jaiserpe\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53:
>   Java returned: 1 BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: It could be that there's mingw runtime DLLs missing. Those libraries are very old. You might be best off compiling them yourself again.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are missing dependent libraries of `libpd`.

You can use [DepndencyWalker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to inspect what is missing.

If you think that all required libraries are there, make sure that they are visible to JVM for loading. More info about loading DLLs on Windows [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: A book about libpd says: "The complete absence of dependencies means that you can build libpd as soon as you have a C compiler". But, once it is built it seems there are dependencies in run time...

Comment: It seems that JVM can't load dependencies, based on your error, regardless of what book is saying. Did you tryied depndency walker before commenting this? It's more reliable than book.

Comment: Using DepndencyWalker I have analysed the dll that appears in the error, which is a dll that is generated in the Temp folder each time I run my Java program. The analysis says: "Error: At least one required implicit or forwarded dependency was not found."

Comment: pore specifically, 9 dll are missing

Answer (score 1):

Those DLLs were built with MinGW. Using the technique here http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gnu.mingw.user/38834 the required DLLs for those builds are:

```
$ x86_64-w64-mingw32-objdump --all-headers java-build/org/puredata/core/natives/windows/x86_64/pthreadGC2.dll | grep 'DLL Name'
    DLL Name: KERNEL32.dll
    DLL Name: msvcrt.dll
    DLL Name: WS2_32.dll
$ x86_64-w64-mingw32-objdump --all-headers java-build/org/puredata/core/natives/windows/x86_64/pdnative.dll | grep 'DLL Name'
    DLL Name: ADVAPI32.dll
    DLL Name: KERNEL32.dll
    DLL Name: msvcrt.dll
    DLL Name: msvcrt.dll
    DLL Name: pthreadGC2.dll
    DLL Name: WS2_32.dll
$ x86_64-w64-mingw32-objdump --all-headers java-build/org/puredata/core/natives/windows/x86/pdnative.dll | grep 'DLL Name'
    DLL Name: ADVAPI32.dll
    DLL Name: KERNEL32.dll
    DLL Name: msvcrt.dll
    DLL Name: msvcrt.dll
    DLL Name: pthreadGC2.dll
    DLL Name: WS2_32.dll
$ x86_64-w64-mingw32-objdump --all-headers java-build/org/puredata/core/natives/windows/x86/pthreadGC2.dll | grep 'DLL Name'
    DLL Name: KERNEL32.dll
    DLL Name: msvcrt.dll
    DLL Name: WS2_32.dll
```

If all those dependencies are no longer found on the system, or just out of date, perhaps recompiling the DLLs would work for you.

Good luck.